# Is there any link between Turing machines and proof theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, computability

I was told (in an informal way) that there exists a close link between Turing machines (or recursive functions, which amounts to the same) and proof theory in the sense that any formal proof can be "expressed" by a Turing machine. To my knowledge such a relationship does not exist, could you please confirm or refute this ?

Comment: Does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830085/what-it-means-lambda-calculus-is-equivalent-to-turing-machine

Comment: There are many relationships between the two. Most obviously, for any recursively axiomatizable theory $T$ (such as ZFC or first-order Peano arithmetic) the set of theorems of $T$ is recursively enumerable. With [more work](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47226/47231#47231) one can even show a kind of converse, that for every r.e. set $W$ there is a finitely axiomatizable theory $T$ whose deductive closure has the same Turing degree as $W$. Ultimately though, this question is too vague in its current form: can you be more precise about what sort of relationship you're looking for?

Comment: As I said, the person who told me that was not very specific and our conversation was quite loose indeed. She told me that, according to her, Turing machines and formal proof are in a "certain sense" equivalent notions : any formal proof can be "expressed" by a Turing machine. I think it is bullshit and comes from a misunderstanding of what is a formal proof, but maybe I am wrong... I know of course that the set of theorems of a theory is r.e., but what told me that person does not seem to refer to that kind of consideration.

Comment: @huurd Maybe what you're looking for is in the linked question: take a look at the Curry-Howard isomorphism/correspondence. You link proof theory with typed lambda-calculus and the latter with Turing machines.